# How do you chain Promises in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I couldn't find any good documentation about how to chain promises in AngularJS.  Can someone please explain to me as clearly as possible how to properly chain promises?

Second, what is the difference between then(success,error) vs, success(fn)/error(fn) method from the Promise API?  Does the then/success/error method only accept callbacks? What should the callback return, and how does data from one promise get passed to the second promise in the promise chain.

Thank-you!

Comment: I wrote a blog post about promises in AngularJS, with a [section on chaining](http://charemza.name/blog/posts/angularjs/promises/angularjs-promises/#chaining-promises), that you might find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining promises:

```
var promise = $http.get(url);

// using then. the first callback is success.
promise.then(function(res){
    console.log("promise then success 1");
});

// using then. the first callback is success + chaining another one.    
promise.then(function(res){
    console.log("promise then success 2");
});

// using success.
promise.success(function(res){
    console.log("success 1");
});

// using error.
promise.error(function(res){
    console.log("error 1");
});

// using then. The first arg is a success callback and the second is an error callback.
promise.then(function(res){
    console.log("promise then success");
},
function(e){
    console.log("promise then error");
});
```

Now what will happen with this promise. If the promise gets resolved all the "success" callbacks will invoke.
If it will get rejected, then all the error callbacks will be invoked.

All the callbacks I've added here are "chained" callbacks.

**Edit**(Thank's Nico)
A promise's callback returns a promise and therefore you can chain them:

```
promise.then(function(res){
   alert("1");
}).then(function(res){
   alert("2");
});
```

Comment: You forget to say that a callback would return the promise itself, allowing you to do something like that: promise.then(function() {}).then(function() {}).then(function() {})